# stopping code at a certain point in a method

Tags: java, methods, joptionpane

I'm making a program for school which inserts contacts into an array lists using JOptionPane/Dialog boxes for input/output.

The problem I'm having is with the Cancel and "X" buttons : when pressed by the user they crash the program.
I figured out using "return" I could stop the method, and that worked for the first dialog box but if information is entered and the user proceeds to the next Dialog box it crashes even though i'm using return again.

So basically what I want to do is if the user presses cancel or "X" to escape the current method it will do so without crashing and return to the main method to carry out other processes.

This code works for the first entry and exits the program successfully:

```
while(nameError)
{
 surname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a Surname");
 if(surname == null)
 {
  return;
 }
 else
 {
  if(!(surname.matches(NamesTest)))
   {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,errorMsg);
   }
  else nameError = false;
  temp[0] = surname;
 }
}
```

but the next line of code in the method for the second Dialog box doesnt:

```
while(nameError1)
{
 if(forename == null)
 {
  return;
 }
 else
 {
  forename = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a Forename");
   if(!(forename.matches(NamesTest)))
   {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,errorMsg);
   }
  else nameError1 = false;
  temp[1] = forename;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DialogExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DialogExample().getNames();
    }

    private void getNames() {
        String firstName = null;
        String lastName = null;
        while (firstName == null || firstName.length() == 0) {
            firstName = getFirstName();
        }
        while (lastName == null || lastName.length() == 0) {
            lastName = getLastName();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello " + firstName + " " + lastName);
    }

    private String getFirstName() {
        String rtn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter First Name");
        if(rtn == null || rtn.length() == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name cannot be empty");
        }
        return rtn;
    }

    private String getLastName() {
        String rtn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter Last Name");
        if(rtn == null || rtn.length() == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name cannot be empty");
        }
        return rtn;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why?